# PHP convert server time to EST Time

Tags: php, html

How to convert the server time to EST Time.

I used date("Y-m-d H:i:s") to store the server time. I want to convert this to EST time.

```
$dt = new DateTime($timestamp);

$dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('EST'));

echo $dt->format('H:i:s');
```

But it is not displaying the correct result. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: [Please check here it may helps you][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559103/php-date-default-timezone-set-eastern-standard-time-est 


there is a nice discription

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago'); //server time zone
echo 'Current Server Time:' . date('m/d/Y H:i:s a') ;
$EasternTimeStamp =mktime(date('H')-6,date('i'),date('s'),date("m"),date("d"),date("Y"));
echo '<br />';
echo 'Current EST Time ' . date('m/d/Y H:i:s a',$EasternTimeStamp) ;
?>
```

[Codepad Demo>>](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Xufyoo)